# Verbs without prepositions

Tags: verbs, prepositions, objects, indirect-objects

I was wondering if there exist some list of all verbs we do not put a preposition after them in a sentence? I'm talking about 2 objects in a sentence - the verb is before indirect object.

Eg. I told her a story.
    She gave me a smile.

I really don't know where to find them and if they have some special name.
Thank you in advance for your time.

Comment: Why do you need a list? Are you going to try and memorize them?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a request for resources (coupled with a repeat question on ditransitive verbs).

Comment: There's also something that mentions not questions about word lists.

Answer (score 3):

They are known as *ditransitive verbs*, or as verbs that take *indirect objects*, or as verbs that undergo *dative shift*.

By [Googling "ditransitive verbs"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22ditransitive+verbs%22), you can find some lists. This one seems pretty good: https://www.cse.unsw.edu.au/~billw/ditransitive.html

Comment: But note that being ditransitive (or bitransitive, same thing) has nothing to do with prepositions. There are prepositions involved, and not every ditransitive verb participates in the Dative Alternation, which is what relates _She gave the book to him_ and _She gave him the book_.